# How can I efficiently format my Ubuntu Live USB to a FAT32 partition?

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted, format, dd

Consider the following situation:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for user: 

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
------------%<-----------------------------
Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
------------%<-----------------------------
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 4008 MB, 4008706048 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 487 cylinders, total 7829504 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x429817b4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           0     2301535     1150768    0  Empty
/dev/sdc2         2279532     2284075        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc1: 1178 MB, 1178386432 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 143 cylinders, total 2301536 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x429817b4

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1p1   *           0     2301535     1150768    0  Empty
/dev/sdc1p2         2279532     2284075        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

What you're seeing here is a Ubuntu Live USB, created by writing

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

if I remember correctly.

I wonder what's the easiest way to format this Live USB to a normal FAT32 partition. I don't want to use it as a Live USB anymore - I just want to use it for storing files in a way that works for both Windows and Ubuntu. If I open GParted, this message appears:

[image: msg_on_opening]

`fdisk` said it was in fact a GPT, so I just click 'yes'...

I then navigate to my partition and try to write a new MBR partition table. When I try to do this, the following message appears:

[image]

which roughly translates to:

```
Encountered libparted bug!

Partition(s) 1 on /dev/sdc is/are written but we couldn't notify the
kernel about the changes, probably because the partitions are still in
use. So, the old partitions will remain active. You should now restart
your computer before making any other changes.
                               Abort / Ignore
```

I have no clue on what button to press here. Furthermore, it's a hassle to restart my computer just because I want to format a Live USB.

So, is there an easier, more efficient way to format my Live USB to a FAT32 partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this a few times myself.

You can fix this like you were doing:

1. Open GParted
2. Click past the warning, I think you need to click "Nee" (no) or if you click Yes, click "Negeren"
3. Disk (Schijf) -> Create partition table (Partitietabel aanmaken)
4. Select MS-DOS
5. Click create / OK

If you don't want to reboot, you can try closing GParted and then unmounting the partition:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdc
```

If you remount it, it should be fine (if not, you still need to reboot):

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove GPT partition table from /dev/sdc first! To do this run :

`sudo parted /dev/sdc`

`mklabel msdos`

`quit`

Then run : `sudo dd if=ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc`again and your problem should be fixed.

That's it!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, but I don't think that will work... AFAIK, `mklabel` will only create a label, not a partition table. Moreover, I'm pretty sure that the `dd` command will undo all the work before

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. My USB drive was with GPT partition table and I could not boot from it. After those commands that I wrote you I fix my problem and I was able to boot from it.